# Can't Access Pre Populated Database

Tags: typescript, sqlite, ionic3

From my research on the interwebs, I've read that pre - populated SQLite databases are allowed in an Ionic 2 application; all you have to do is simply add it to the /www directory.

I've attempted this multiple times and have not been successful whatsoever. When I go to select from one of the tables I've pre - populated, I get an error saying that the table doesn't exist.

My package.json settings:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
"@ionic-native/sqlite": "^3.4.4",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
"@types/cordova": "0.0.34",
"ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.1.1",
"sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
"typescript": "~2.2.1"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
"cordova-plugin-whitelist",
"cordova-plugin-console",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar",
"cordova-plugin-device",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
"description": "eqm: Equipment Manager"
```

The code for accessing my database (well, one of the tables at least :) ) is :

```
public getPeople() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    this.sql.create({
        name: "eqm.db",
        location: "default"
    }).then((db2: SQLiteObject) => {
            let players = new Array<PlayerModel>();
            db2.executeSql("SELECT * FROM players", []).then((data) => {
                if(data.rows.length > 0) {
                    for(let i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
                        var model = new PlayerModel(data.rows.item(i).playerName,  data.rows.item(i).playerBarcode);
                        players.push(model);
                    }
                }
                resolve(players);

            }, (error) => {
                reject(error);

            });
    }));
}
```

In my plugin directory, I noticed that there is:
    cordova-sqlite-ext
    cordova-sqlite-storage

I believe the first was installed to this directory when I added my android platform. I have tried small test projects and only added `cordova-sqlite-storage`, but my tests with a pre populated db were unsuccessful.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you check the sqlite db connection ? is code able to find sqlite file? I would recommend to put a condition and log to check

Comment: @MuhammadAhsan from what I can tell, no, it cannot find the file.